Mar Samuel and Dina d'malkhuta dina dispute
From Wikipedia:

In the opinion of some, for the exiled Jews their submission to
gentile rulers was viewed more as a "pragmatic recognition of brute
force" than anything else.

Do I understand it correctly that submission to the laws that are established by a group that takes power in the land we find ourselves living in is completely rabbinical?

It depends what land and what group! Please clarify. And what do you mean by "completely rabbinical"? There are several approaches to why we regard the law of the land as such; contemporary authority Rabbi Asher Weiss feels it is a matter of extrapolating the value of preservation of life to the broader scale -- "without the fear of government, every mean would swallow their friend alive."

What I mean is we have our own laws and only at a certain point did we get into halachic decisions a reason based on rabbinical decision based on discernment... instead of Torah it's based on discernment
